# Concatenate immutable ruby strings with codepoints

Tags: ruby, string, encoding

Prior to Ruby 2.3, which introduced optional frozen strings, a string could be appended to using the shovel operator ("<<", aliased as "concat"). However, the shovel operator would do more than just append a string, it would treat digits as code-points and [perform various checks for the current and appending string encodings](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e1762942a6861a583263945efa3230a5faefaf53/string.c#L3028L3089)

```
$ x = "hello"
$ x << 33            # or: x << 0b111000 , x << 0x111, etc
#=> "hello!"
```

With the optional #frozen_string_literal configuration option set, strings are no longer mutable, so it's not possible to use the shovel operator, which mutates the object it's called on. However, creating strings by reassigning the variable appears to require a lot of the encoding work to be explicit, rather than implicit

```
$ x = "hello"
$ x += 33
#=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Integer into String
```

I often see resolved by doing the following:

```
$ x = "hello"
$ x += [33].pack("U")
#=> hello!
```

The pack method requires a lot to be known about the input, as listed [under the directives for Array.pack](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-pack). So far I've found this to be a pain when replacing mutable string concatenation ("x << y") with variable reassignment "x += y" in an existing code base.

For reference, I'm trying to update [someone's existing project to use immutable strings](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket/blob/e88b5321c91e775c5f648cd93a2a288a285c5251/lib/em-websocket/framing07.rb#L149), however it's not always clear to me exactly what the string encoding is. The bytes vary a lot between 8-bit, 16-bit, etc requiring pack('n'), pack('c'), pack('U'), etc.

While I assume the best answer is to be explicit in the string encoding, avoiding potentials bugs later on, since I have access to both objects, nothing about immutability itself should dictate that more information is now necessary.

Is there any easy replacement for the shovel operator that can provide the same kind of encoding inference on the existing and appending string? Ideally something that hits the same C code as "x.concat(y)" but doesn't make an in place change, leveraging the encoding checks same encoding checks while not violating immutability?

Thanks!

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are after; what does your array contain? raw bytes of an encoding compatible with `x`? If so, this might work for you: `x += bytes.pack('C*').force_encoding(x.encoding)` - always just get a string with those raw bytes (`'C'`), then reinterpret the encoding as appropriate.

Comment: I dunno if this is the answer you're looking for because it possibly loses the optimization, but you can use mutable string methods even with the `# frozen_string_literal: true` comment by using the `String.new` constructor: `String.new("hello").concat(33)`

Comment: @maxpleaner: Equivalent to `+"hello" << 33`; but you end up with an unfrozen string that way (which may not be what OP wants)

Comment: @Amadan Thanks! That solved it for me: `x += bytes.pack('C*').force_encoding(x.encoding)`. And in the other cases where x and y were both strings but `x += y` failed while `x << y` succeeded, `x += y.force_encoding(x.encoding)` did the trick.

Comment: @maxpleaner thanks for the tip. Was hoping to keep all strings frozen, but that's a useful workaround if/when I need it.

Comment: Again, not sure what you need, but you might want `x += y.encode(x.encoding)` instead. `force_encoding` keeps the underlying bytes constant and changes how they're interpreted; `encode` keeps the interpretation constant and changes the underlying bytes to fit the new encoding.

Comment: you might want to make this an answer @Amadan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to concatenate two strings, they need to be in a compatible encoding. `String#<<` will try to find an encoding compatible with both operands, and convert the first operand to that encoding.

```
a = "a".encode('ascii-8bit')
a.encoding   #=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
b = "b"
b.encoding   #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
a << b       #=> "ab"
a.encoding   #=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
c = "ø"
c.encoding   #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
a << c       #=> "abø"
a.encoding   #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Note in the last row how the encoding of `a` changed to accommodate the character not present in `ASCII-8BIT` encoding.

If the right argument is a number, this number is interpreted as a codepoint in the current encoding. If that encoding is `ASCII-8BIT`, the number can go from `0` to `255`; if the encoding is `UTF-8`, it can go up to `1114111` (`0x10FFFF`); other encodings have yet different ranges.

To replicate the same functionality with immutable strings, ideally, you would do this:

```
x += y.encode(x.encoding)   # instead of destructive `x << y`
x += 33.chr(x.encoding)     # instead of destructive `x << 33`
```

Note: Originally I thought you had raw bytes of the appropriate encoding, so I suggested `String#force_encoding` instead of `String#encode`, but if I understand correctly what you meant, this will actually give you wrong result.